# docker can't not start postgresql server with a existing data directory

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have an existing postgres database just called DB1 and want to docker it, but I can't start the server just set the PGDATA to the DB1's data directory, and the message was

> directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" is not a database cluster directory

but the server can start correctly in the host, why?

Comment: Sounds similar to this; https://github.com/zenoamaro/ansible-postgresql/issues/5